# Efficient way to exclude a specific value from a TreeMap

Tags: java, data-structures, treemap

I am trying to achieve the best performance for my app. At some point in the code, i want to retrieve all the values from a map except one that corresponds to a specific key.

Now, if i wanted to retrieve all the values i would use this:

```
map.values();
```

and assuming that the TreeMap class is created efficiently, the 'values()' method is just returning a refference so --> O(1).

In my case though i want to exclude the value of a specific key. This code:

```
Set<String> set = new ...
for (String key: map.keySet()) {
   if (!key.equals("badKey")) {
      set.add(map.get(key));
   }
}
```

has a complexity of N*(logN) which is much slower than the initial O(1) and this is caused by the need of removing only one value.

---

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: how frequently this map changes i.e. you put/remove from map?

Comment: In the first case, you get a Collection<String>. In the second one, you get a TreeMap<String, String>. So, what do you actually want as a result? What do you do with the returned collection or map?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to insert the bad key in the first place when creating the map? Maybe you can take a performance hit while creating the map instead of taking a hit to serve a request.

Comment: Return a view, without this particular key/value mapping.

Comment: @almas shaikh: it is not changing frequently.

Comment: @JB Nizet: you are right, i have changed the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @bot: i cant avoid it, the key is not bad in the meaning that i dont want it in my structure, i just want to exclude it once.

Comment: @Mario Can you show code that will actually use the new Set that does not contain the key? If you know what key should not be looked up, just put a check for the same while looking up the map instead of creating a new set altogether?

Comment: @bot The problem was the 'checking' itself. If i iterate overthe keys, every time i call map.get(key) to retrieve the value, costs me O(logN). This is what i wanted to avoid. Eran's answer does the trick so i am covered. Thanks for your answer though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `entrySet` instead of `keySet`. This way it would take O(1) to find out if a given value belongs to the key you wish to exclude.

You can call `entrySet` any time you need to iterate over the values, and exclude the bad key while iterating over them. This would give you the same complexity as iterating over the `values()` Collection would.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
map.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals(keyToFilter))
  .map(Map.Entry::getValue);
```

Finish with either `forEach` or `toCollection(Collectors.TO_SET)`, or simply return the stream.

Sorry if the code doesn't compile exactly, it's from memory and I haven't touched the java 8 APIs in a few months, but you should get the drift. ;)

Comment: Not sure if the OP is looking for a Java 8 solution. The question is specifically tagged as java.

Comment: @bot 8 is current Java. Seems you've got it upside down.

Comment: I am actually using java 7 but i did not specify it, so this is on me :) Still thanks for the alternative solution. This may help others who use java 8.

Comment: @Marko Stackoverflow has a java-8 tag to avoid the confusion. If someone is looking for a Java-8 solution, they would say so explicitly by using this tag.

Comment: @bot And what if someone asks for *any* solution which works with current Java? The world is not divided into java and java-8.

Comment: @Marko As a matter of fact it is. I am sure a majority of the applications are running on Java 6 and 7. Java 8 is a major step ahead in the way we Java programmers write code.

Comment: @bot Java 7 is just two months shy of the End-of-Updates date. The answers should by no means *assume* lesser versions.

Comment: @Marko Interesting. I didn't know that Java 7 was nearing it's last few updates. Although, I don't see organizations moving to Java 8 until and unless they are building a new system from scratch. So the decision to use Java 8 is not based on how many updates are pending for Java 7. Maybe a better option would be to provide both Java 8 and non Java 8 answers till the time the industry catches up.

Comment: @bot Well, that's what usually does happen (like here). And yes,businesses are notoriously inert and my personal interest is contributing with whatever push I can :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create set from `map.values()` and after it remove "badKey" value from this set.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(map.values());
String badValue = map.get("badKey");
set.remove(badValue);
```

Comment: This works too... It bounds you to use HashSet for optimum performance - i want everything sorted so: TreeSet - but it is a pretty good solution even with TreeSet. Thanks!